# Flutter For Web Application launches TypeError Exception

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am building a Flutter For Web application and the code is working perfectly at the moment, but sometimes, when i open the application, even though the app is working, i found that an Exception has been thrown.
Here is what i find:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t3.onPointerDataPacket is not a function
    at src__engine.PointerBinding.new.[_onPointerData] (pointer_binding.dart:85)
    at pointer_binding.dart:207
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (pointer_binding.dart:143)
```

what is this and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run app by

```
void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),

));
```